# Изменять стиль другого элемента при наведении на блок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли менять стили тега `<img>` при наведении курсора на блок `<div>`? Допустим, если я наведу мышь на блок, то ширина изображения изменится с `200px` до `400px`. Эти элементы не вложенные и находятся в разных местах, но нужно, чтобы они были связаны. Как такое можно реализовать?

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<img src='link.png'>
<div>Клик!</div>
```

Comment: Ты понимаешь, что ответ на твой вопрос: **да, можно**. Если есть что-то конкретное, то сразу пиши. Что же вы за любители такие,  нравится когда клещами из вас тянешь всё по кусочку. Тренинг шпионов что ли

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, приложил пример, но вообще меня интересовала сама технология, как можно влиять на стили другого элемента.

Comment: Ну например, в данном случае, через изменения соседа слева (prev) - если через js . еще через соседа справа, через общего предка, через связку идентификатор-класс. да любая технология. их десятки,  всё зависит от ситуации.... интересует что: js или css?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, желательно CSS, но поскольку я не знал, возможно ли такое, приложил еще и JS

Comment: в данном конкретном случае через чистый css нельзя. можно через препроцессоры разве что (хотя я немного сомневаюсь). в данном случае только через js и например previousSibling (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)

Comment: Кстати, решения из ответа не сработают в случае нескольких дивов и картинок на странице. Надо это иметь в виду... точнее будут работать совсем не так как ожидается... а во втором примере даже достаточно css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение на javascript:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var img = document.querySelector('img');

div.onmouseover = function(e) {
  img.style.width = '400px';
};

div.onmouseout = function(e) {
  img.style.width = '';
};
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>Текст</div>
<img src="https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
```

---

Решение на jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('div').hover(function() {
    // навели мышь на элемент
    $('img').css('width', '400px');
  }, function() {
    // убрали мышь с элемента
    $('img').css('width', '');
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Текст</div>
<img src="https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
```